# Install b43 firmware from Arch Install Media

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, broadcom

I'm currently attempting to install Arch on my dual booted Linux box, however my system uses b43 which I have and used post-install on Mint and Ubuntu.

I'm not sure how to run `makepkg` from the Arch install or how to add to the ISO to use for the install?

My current system config:

```
sda 250gib
sda1 6gib -mint 16 x86_64
sda2 6gib - ubuntux86_64
sda3 6gib - intended arch
sda4 12gib swap
sda5 220 gib home
```

My system is a Dell d620 with Nvidia support and running b43, non detected by default. I have the `tar.gz` from the Mint and Ubuntu installs but not sure how to use `makepkg` that will work for Arch from off my runnning system.

Comment: From the Arch chroot, install `base-devel` and then `wget` the AUR package ([b43-firmware or b43-firmware-legacy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/B43#b43.2Fb43legacy)) and install it with `makepkg -i`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Your comment appears to be an answer. Please post it as such. Otherwise OP can't accept it, and has already tried posting a thank-you as an answer...